# WPF, telerik - GroupRows by Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik

I want to use the `ShowGroupPanel` in the telerik: RadGridView but I want to group them by a Property.

MainClass -Object

- Id
- GroupProperty
- Name

how can I Group my Rows after GroupProperty?

```
<telerik:RadGridView AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True" CanUserReorderColumns="True" 
    CanUserDeleteRows="False" CanUserInsertRows="False" ShowGroupPanel="True" EnableRowVirtualization="True" Name="GridViewlist" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=List, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" SelectionUnit="FullRow" >
    <telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can turn on/off grouping on a column by setting the Groupable property.

If you want to allow grouping on other columns, but show your GroupProperty by default you may want to use:

```
<telerik:RadGridView.GroupDescriptors>
    <telerik:GroupDescriptor Member="GroupProperty"
                                 SortDirection="Ascending">

     </telerik:GroupDescriptor>
</telerik:RadGridView.GroupDescriptors>
```